# changing innertext of asp:linkbutton is throwing error: Expected ')'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm sure I'm just missing some formatting or not escaping something right, but what am I doing wrong here?

```
<asp:Linkbutton ID="btnExecutePasswordChange" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3" 
     OnClientClick="$(this).html('<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Please wait...');"
     OnClick="btnExecutePasswordChange_Click">Change Password</asp:Linkbutton>
```

I'm using bootstrap 3.2 and font awesome 4.2.

The error is:

```
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to escape the single quotes in the single-quoted string.

Alter

`'<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Please wait...'`

to

`'<i class=\'fa fa-spinner fa-spin\'></i> Please wait...'`

Comment: That worked. I knew it had to be something like that. Thanks.